# Is it possible to do soap/wsdl requests as in SoapUI?

Tags: emacsclient

Emacs 27.1

To work with wsdl file I use SoapUI 5.7.

Steps:

1. Load wsdl file to SoapUI.
   As result it's show me all methods:

[image]

2. set credentials
3. Create and run any of method
   [image]

And it's work just fine.

So the question is:
Is it possible to do same things in Emacs?